# Variance analysis on boosting approachs, Is there any guarantee that boosting will not worse the weak learner variance or even get it better?

Tags: probability, inference, boosting, ensemble-learning, bias-variance-tradeoff

I'm looking for a theorical justification why boosting does work in pratice, I'm almost sure that this reduces the bias of their weak learners (assuming all weak learners have the same bias), but I don't know why boosting approachs don't worse the variance (or even get they better by reducing them) since if they do so they wouldn't work very well in practice.

Take a set of weak learners $\hat{h}_m(x) \in \mathcal{H}$ , $1<m \leq M$, where $\mathcal{H}$ is their class, that is all weak learners have the same functional form and they differ only due to its adjusted parameter values, now one takes a boosting model $\hat{f}(x)$ to be:

$\hat{f}(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^{M}\hat{h}_m(x)$

Where the weak learners have the same distribution (is this a good assumptions for boosting?) but they are not necessarily independent.

Now take $V(\hat{h_m}(x))={\sigma}(x)$ to be the variance of any weak learner (I'm using $\sigma$ to denote variance) so by some math we have that the variance of $\hat{f}(x)$ is given by:

$V(\hat{f}(x))=M.{\sigma}(x)+\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{M}\sum_{j=1}^{M}cov(\hat{h}_i(x),\hat{h}_j(x))$

Since the equality over their distributions we have that $cov(\hat{h}_i(x),\hat{h}_j(x))=c(x)$ where it doesn't depend from $i,j$ so:

$V(\hat{f}(x))=M.{\sigma}(x)+M^2 c(x)$

Note that the boosting model does have the same variance of any weak learner if $M^2 c(x)=\sigma(x)-M \sigma(x)$, by some math $c(x)=\displaystyle\frac{\sigma(x)(1-M)}{M^2}$.

That's $\hat{f}(x)$ doesn't worse the variance, if the boosting turn the weak learners variance better so $V(\hat{f}(x)) < \sigma(x)$ this happens if:

$c(x) < \displaystyle\frac{\sigma(x)(1-M)}{M^2}$

So it would be worth using boosting if:

$c(x) \leq \displaystyle\frac{\sigma(x)(1-M)}{M^2}$

Since if it holds so the variance in the worst case would be the same as the variance of the weak learners. So here is my question given by the statings bellow:

1 - Is that identically distributed assumption 'weak' for boosting? That's for the most algorithms it'll hold or for the most cases in practice.

2 - The main point I'd like to know is if boosting modeling guarantees me that $c(x) \leq \displaystyle\frac{\sigma(x)(1-M)}{M^2}$, if so why?

Comment: if you think it would be better get moved to data science so do that, I'm not sure if this question is better placed here since the most of questions I've been seeing here is regardless to ensemble learning.